# Attributes names are not unique in Weka 3.8

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka

I am having trouble importing a CSV file. I get the following error: File "filename.csv" not recognised as an 'CSV data files' file. Reason: Attributes names are not unique! Causes: '2' '1'.

Can anyone tell me how to fix these issues? I am using Weka 3.8 on a Windows 10 64 bit laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the CSV you're trying to import?

Comment: I am using NSL-KDDCup Dataset

Comment: as others have correctly answered, the feature labels(names) need to be unique. Look at the link bellow for more info: https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/Witten_et_al_2016_appendix.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure to have a column name that's going to be unique vis-a-vis attribute values. This happens for me when I applied StringtoWordVector and get strings which are of the same name as my column name. Just give a good column name :)

Comment: u're my hero =)

Answer (score 0):

WEKA will assume that the first row of data is the names of the columns, but the version of the NSL-KDDCup Dataset that I looked at on
[github](https://github.com/jmnwong/NSL-KDD-Dataset)
did not have column headers. Since the first row had some repeated values,  you get this error message. I will suggest two solutions.

1. The above noted github has a weka-friendly arff file with the data.
2. Add column headers to the csv file. What should the column headers be? They are listed in the arff file. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It happens when attribute name is same, in more than one column of the excel sheet. Just rename the column name which are same. It should be unique. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I uploaded a dataset to weka. When I examined the columns of the dataset, I found that the same column name was present. When I changed the name of one of the two different columns of the 'fwd header length' value, the error was fixed.

[image]